# Getting error Firebase. createUser failed: First argument must contain the key "password" Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm new to angular and I'm following a chatapp tutorial from online. I'm getting this the error "Firebase.createUser failed: First argument must contain the key "password" " when I try to register with an email and password. The app isn't complete yet, I just finished the auth part. Google answers suggested that I update to the latest angularfire, which I did ( 1.1.3). No idea what to do.

Register state in app.js:

```
  .state('register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'auth/register.html',
    controller:'AuthCtrl as authCtrl',

    resolve:{
      requireNoAuth: function($state,Auth){
        return Auth.$requireAuth()
          .then(function(auth){
          $state.go('home');
          },
          function(error){
            return;
          });
        }
      }

  })
```

authController.js

```
angular.module('chatApp')

  .controller('AuthCtrl', function (Auth, $state) {

    //Using 'Controller as syntax', instead of $scope, we use 'this' to make controller

    var authCtrl = this;

    //user object controller

    authCtrl.user = {

      email:'',
      pass:''

    };

    //login object controller. Firebase provides functions.  Using promises. ( either it's fufilled, or rejected)

    authCtrl.login = function () {



      Auth.authWithPassword(authCtrl.user)
        // .then takes in 2 parameters( onSuccess, onFaliure)

        //if successfull, go home
        .then(function (auth) {

            $state.go('home');
          },

          //if failed, set error in controller, so we can call it and display message later
          function (error) {
            authCtrl.error = error;

          });

    };

//registering user
    authCtrl.register = function () {
      Auth.$createUser(authCtrl.user)

        // prompt user to login if successful
        .then(function (user) {
            authCtrl.login();
          },
//else bring up error
          function (error) {

            authCtrl.error = error;
          })


    }






});
```

authFactory.js

```
angular.module('chatApp')

.factory('Auth',function($firebaseAuth,FirebaseUrl){

  var declare= new Firebase(FirebaseUrl);
  var auth=$firebaseAuth(declare);
  return auth




});
```

Comment: Do you tried to rename the field authCtrl.user { pass: ... } to { password: }?

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo haha that removed the error! thanks man I'm so dumb. Is password like a specific keyword, why doesn't it work with pass? Now everytime I register, it says "The specified email address is invalid".??

Answer (score 0):

It's `password`, not `pass`.

Secondly, you're incorrectly resolving the user in your route config. Rather than using the promise chain in resolve, you just need to return the promise.

```
  .state('register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'auth/register.html',
    controller:'AuthCtrl as authCtrl',

    resolve:{
      requireNoAuth: function($state,Auth){
        return Auth.$requireAuth(); // return the promise
      }
    }

  })
```

Then in the `run()` phase, you can listen for routing errors:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      $location.path("/home");
    }
  });
});
```

[**Check out the AngularFire docs on using Auth with Routing for more information.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers)

Comment: Ok thanks! So will this run phase work for all my other states? I have a login state, profile state etc.  I only want to run this resolve on my login and register state. So it will only work for the state that contain $requireAuth right?

Comment: Did this answer help you?